# How to separate controller method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I start with Laravel, I write API. I have a method in TestController that checks if the student has correctly inserted data and has access to the exam solution. I do not think it's a good idea to have the whole method in the controller, but I have no idea how to separate it. I think about politics, but I have to have several models for one policy, maybe I can try to put part of the method on AuthorizeStudentRequest or try it in a different way? Of course, now I am returning 200 with the message, but I have to return 422 or another code with errors, but I have not done it because of my problem.

```
public function authorizeStudent(AuthorizeStudentRequest $request)
{
    $hash = $request->input('hash');
    $token = $request->input('token');

    $exam = Exam::where([['hash', $hash], ['token', $token]])->first();

    if($exam == null)
        return ['message' => 'Exam does not exist.'];  

    $user = $exam->user_id;
    $studentFirstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $studentLastname = $request->input('lastname');

    $student = Student::where([
        ['firstname', $studentFirstname],
        ['lastname', $studentLastname],
        ['user_id', $user]
    ])->first();

    if($student == null)
        return ['message' => 'Student does not exist.'];

    $classroom = Classroom::where([
        ['name', $classroomName],
        ['user_id', $user]
    ])->first();

    if($classroom == null)
        return ['message' => 'Classroom does not exist.'];

    if($student->classroom_id != $classroom->id)
        return ['message' => 'Student is not in classroom.'];

    if($exam->classrooms()->where(['classroom_id', $classroom->id], ['access', 1])->first() == null)
        return ['message' => 'Class does not access to exam yet.'];


}
```

Comment: You can use Laravel policies for this type of authorization. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you rather pass the primary keys of the selected `$exam`, `$student` and `$classroom` models to your controller from the form and validate whether they exist in the corresponding tables, rather than having to check their existence using a bunch of different columns.

If you pass the primary keys, you could use the ['exists' validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-exists) to check if they exist. For example, in your AuthorizeStudentRequest class you could have the following function:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'exam_id' => 'required|exists:exams',
        'student_id' => 'required|exists:students',
        'classroom_id' => 'required|exists:classrooms',
    ];
}
```

Otherwise, if you really need to use the different columns to check the existence of the exam, student and classroom, you could create [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules) and use them in your AuthorizeStudentRequest class. For example, create a custom validation rule that checks whether the exam exists as follows:

`$php artisan make:rule ExamExists`

```
class ExamExists implements Rule
{
    private $token;
    private $hash;

    public function __construct($token, $hash)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->hash = $hash;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return Exam::where([['hash', $hash], ['token', $token]])->count() > 0;
    }
}
```

And then you can use the custom validation rule in your request as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'hash' => ['required', new ExamExists($this->hash, $this->token)],
         ... other validation rules ...
    ]
}
```

For checking whether a student has access to a classroom or a class has access to an exam, you could use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#writing-policies).

Answer (score 1):

API resources present a way to easily transform our models into JSON responses. It acts as a transformation layer that sits between our Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned by our API. API resources is made of two entities: a resource class and a resource collection. A resource class represents a single model that needs to be transformed into a JSON structure, while a resource collection is used for transforming collections of models into a JSON structure.

Both the resource class and the resource collection can be created using artisan commands:

```
 // create a resource class
    $ php artisan make:resource UserResource

    // create a resource collection using either of the two commands
    $ php artisan make:resource Users --collection
    $ php artisan make:resource UserCollection
```

Before diving into all of the options available to you when writing resources, let's first take a high-level look at how resources are used within Laravel. A resource class represents a single model that needs to be transformed into a JSON structure. For example, here is a simple User resource class:

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

Every resource class defines a toArray method which returns the array of attributes that should be converted to JSON when sending the response. Notice that we can access model properties directly from the $this variable. More information here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources